# Is there any way to import or convert CouchDB to MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, couchdb

I have a **CouchDB** how do I export or convert it to **MongoDB**?

```
root@nkumar-desktop:/home/nkumar# curl -X GET http:/localhost/my_first_db

{"db_name":"my_first_db",
 "doc_count":2,
 "doc_del_count":0,
 "update_seq":6,
 "purge_seq":0,
 "compact_running":false,
 "disk_size":20569,
 "instance_start_time":"1371104307474652",
 "disk_format_version":4}
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB comes with [mongoimport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) which will import json data.

However, this wont convert the date types - A manual import script could be used to convert:  `"instance_start_time":"1371104307474652"` into a datetime - so then you can query against it as a datetime - rather than a string.

Comment: This doesn't work, It only imported about half of the records.

Comment: What did the import say?